# Print an array from a function inside Angular HTML

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm doing an app where I print some cars (I receive them from the database) and in one column I have one string with multiple tags that are divided by commas, I made a function to receive that as an array of words and then print each word for make tags, but I don't really know how to call the function or how to do it because it's repeating multiple times when it shouldn't do that.

```html
<!-- Category Card -->
<div *ngFor="let car of cars" class="col-md-4">
  <div class="card-image-overlay m-auto" id="tags">
    {{separar(car?.tags)}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Then the code of the function "separar":

```js
public separar(string) {
  var palabras = [];
  palabras = string.split(",");
  for (var i = 0 ; i < palabras.length ; i++) {
    document.getElementById("tags").innerHTML +=
      ("<span class='card-detail-badge'>" + palabras[i] + "</span>");
  }
}
```

I'm getting this:

[image]

and it should only print 3 times those tags.

Probably is a mistake very easy but Im new to angular and my teacher doesn't know why it doesn't work. :(

Comment: Use an `ngFor` https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf instead of appending to the DOM directly, otherwise it might be uncontrolled by angular. Also, we are assuming `car?.tags` has no duplicates, does it?

Comment: `document.getElementById("tags").innerHTML` --> Red flag. Stop right here. This has _nothing_ to do in an angular app, that's not how Angular works.

Comment: I'd highly suggest taking the angular tutorial over at [their official site](https://angular.io/tutorial). It will teach you the basics of how to use variables in templates as well as the 'angular way' of html manipulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ngFor` to do it "the Angular way"

```
getTags(tags: sring): string[] {
  return tags.split(',');
}
```

```html
<!-- Category Card -->
<div *ngFor="let car of cars" class="col-md-4">
  <div class="card-image-overlay m-auto" id="tags">
    <span class='card-detail-badge' *ngFor="let tag of getTags(car?.tags)">
      {{tag}}
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try returning the HTML string from the template function instead.

Also, avoid common (sometimes "reserved") words for variables i.e use `tagListStr` instead of `string`.

```js
public separar(tagListStr) {
  return tagListStr
    .split(",")
    .map(tag => `<span class='card-detail-badge'>${tag}</span>`)
    .join('');
}
```